# How to install cx_freeze for converting Python 3.10 Scripts to Executables?

Tags: python

Hello I can't find any `cx_freeze` version for `Python 3.10` As it's not available on Internet. I needed it because only `cx_freeze` can convert my script into executable.

Is there any other way to convert `Python 3.10` to exe without any errors even the `pyinstaller` gives error while converting it's code.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider downgrade to Python 3.9.
Last version of Cx_freeze and Python 3.9.9 is working fine.
For further help: https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_script.html#setup-script

step by step:

```
install python 3.9.9
pip install cx-freeze
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
cxfreeze -c hello.py --target-dir dist
```

Answer (score 0):

Build it for Windows and tested with PyQt6 all works fine

Link to download: https://github.com/egormartiniuc/wheels.git